# Discord.js for loop behaving oddly

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a kick command for a Discord bot in Discord.js. How it works is a previous function passes an array of user IDs to attempt to kick from the server. For some reason, the for loop is repeating more than it should and the `i` value doesn't seem to change sometimes.

Here's my code:

```
exports.kick = async (guild, targets, member, reason, bot) => {
    var modRoleQuery = await exports.queryModRole(guild, member, bot);
    var outputMessage = '';
    if (modRoleQuery === false && !member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') && member != guild.me) return `You do not have permission to execute this command.`;
    else if (targets.length === 0) return `Command usage: ${config.prefix}kick <@mentions/IDs> [reason]`;
    else if (!guild.me.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) return `I require the \`Kick Members\` permission to execute this command.`;
    else if (targets.length > 10) return `You may only kick 10 members at a time.`;
    else if (reason.length > 1000) return `The kick reason must not exceed 1000 characters. Currently, it is ${reason.length}.`;
    for (i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
        console.log(`checking ${targets[i]}, ${i}`);
        let targetMember = guild.member(targets[i]);
        if (targetMember) {
            if (targetMember.kickable) {
                let targetMemberModRole = await exports.queryModRole(guild, targetMember, bot);
                if ((targetMemberModRole || targetMember.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) && !member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
                    outputMessage += `Unable to kick \`${targetMember.user.tag}\`: Only administrators can kick people with the moderator role and/or admin perms.\n`
                } else {
                    await targetMember.user.send(`You were kicked from ${targetMember.guild.name} by ${member.user.tag}:\nReason: \`${reason}\``).catch(err => {});
                    await targetMember.kick(`[${member.user.tag}] ${reason}`);
                    exports.modLogEvent(bot, guild, `KICK`, targetMember.user, member.user, reason);
                    
                    outputMessage += `Successfully kicked \`${targetMember.user.tag}\`\n`;
                }
            } else {
                outputMessage += `Unable to kick \`${targetMember.user.tag}\`: I don't have permission to kick them.\n`;
            }
        } else {
            outputMessage += `Unable to kick \`${targets[i]}\`: They don't seem to be in this server.\n`;
            console.log(`${targets[i]} is not a member`)
        }
    }
    outputMessage += `**Kick Reason:**\n\`${reason}\``;
    return outputMessage;
}
```

When the size of the array is 1, this works as expected, however when it is more than 1, it doesn't. I've put in some `console.log()` functions for debugging purposes.

[image: Here's the command I ran]

[image: Here's the output]

For some reason, the `i` value gets stuck on 1. I also ran it a bit earlier (this is before I added the `console.log()`s) and it behaved even more oddly:

[image]

I've been trying to debug this for over a day now and I'm not getting anywhere. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should check what is in `targets` as input

Comment: I did that before, the array is as expected.

Comment: is the function called once or called for each target you add in input? it's odd that you have 6 logs when entering 3 inputs

Comment: Seems that the run is: 
(Kick 1 --> OK)

(Kick 1 --> KO
Kick 2 --> OK)

(Kick 1 --> KO
Kick 2 --> KO
Kick 3 --> OK)

Comment: The function is run once, here's the code in my index.js:
https://hastebin.com/vapuwoxiyu.csharp
not sure why exactly it says csharp

Comment: The issue appears to be that the for loop is repeating itself partially, if that's even possible.

Comment: There may be some bugs caused by **scope**. Can you try explicitly declaring `i`, i.e. changing `for (i = 0; i < targets.length; i++)` to `for (let i = 0; i < targets.length; i++)`?